# Read PMU counters using wrmsrl and rdmsrl

Tags: c, linux-kernel, kernel-module, intel-pmu, msr

I'm trying to read the LLC cache miss hardware counter in a Linux kernel module on an Intel Xeon gold (Skylake generation) processor. The result of the following code is always zero:

```c
#define PMC_ESEL_UMASK_SHIFT 8
#define PMC_ESEL_CMASK_SHIFT 24

#define PMC_ESEL_ENTRY(event, umask, cmask)       \
    (((event)&0xFFUL) |                           \
     (((umask)&0xFFUL) << PMC_ESEL_UMASK_SHIFT) | \
     (((cmask)&0xFFUL) << PMC_ESEL_CMASK_SHIFT))

#define PMC_ESEL_USR (1ULL << 16)    /* User Mode */
#define PMC_ESEL_OS (1ULL << 17)     /* Kernel Mode */
#define PMC_ESEL_EDGE (1ULL << 18)   /* Edge detect */
#define PMC_ESEL_PC (1ULL << 19)     /* Pin control */
#define PMC_ESEL_INT (1ULL << 20)    /* APIC interrupt enable */
#define PMC_ESEL_ANY (1ULL << 21)    /* Any thread */
#define PMC_ESEL_ENABLE (1ULL << 22) /* Enable counters */
#define PMC_ESEL_INV (1ULL << 23)    /* Invert counter mask */

/* architectural performance counters (works on all Intel CPUs) */
#define PMC_ARCH_CORE_CYCLES PMC_ESEL_ENTRY(0x3C, 0x00, 0)
#define PMC_ARCH_INSTR_RETIRED PMC_ESEL_ENTRY(0xC0, 0x00, 0)
#define PMC_ARCH_REF_CYCLES PMC_ESEL_ENTRY(0x3C, 0x01, 0)
#define PMC_ARCH_LLC_REF PMC_ESEL_ENTRY(0x2E, 0x4F, 0)
#define PMC_ARCH_LLC_MISSES PMC_ESEL_ENTRY(0x2E, 0x41, 0)
#define PMC_ARCH_BRANCHES PMC_ESEL_ENTRY(0xC4, 0x00, 0)
#define PMC_ARCH_BRANCH_MISSES PMC_ESEL_ENTRY(0xC5, 0x00, 0)

#define PMC_LLC_MISSES (PMC_ARCH_LLC_MISSES | PMC_ESEL_USR | PMC_ESEL_OS | \
                        PMC_ESEL_ENABLE)
#define PMC_LLC_MISSES_ANY (PMC_ARCH_LLC_MISSES | PMC_ESEL_USR | PMC_ESEL_OS | \
                            PMC_ESEL_ANY | PMC_ESEL_ENABLE)

/* enable/disable perf counter */
#define CORE_PERF_GLOBAL_CTRL_ENABLE_PMC_0 (0x1)
#define CORE_PERF_GLOBAL_CTRL_ENABLE_PMC_1 (0x2)

void test(void)
{
    u64 val;
    wrmsrl(MSR_CORE_PERF_FIXED_CTR_CTRL, 0x333);
    wrmsrl(MSR_CORE_PERF_GLOBAL_CTRL,
           CORE_PERF_GLOBAL_CTRL_ENABLE_PMC_0 |
               CORE_PERF_GLOBAL_CTRL_ENABLE_PMC_1 |
               (1UL << 32) | (1UL << 33) | (1UL << 34));
    wrmsrl(MSR_P6_EVNTSEL0, PMC_LLC_MISSES);
    rdmsrl(MSR_P6_PERFCTR0, val);
    printk(KERN_DEBUG "The LLC-Miss value is: %llu\n", val);
}
```

Could anyone please help target the issue with this code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that I missed using `rdmsrl_on_core` and `wrmsrl_on_cpu` to enable and read PMC on each core. I'm attaching a working version of the kernel module code in case anyone needs it in the future:

```c
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/init.h>

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
MODULE_AUTHOR("Mohammad Siavashi");
MODULE_DESCRIPTION("A sample LLC miss counter reader");

#define IA32_PERF_GLOBAL_CTRL_ENABLE 0x70000000f
#define LLC_EVENT 0x0043412e
#define IA32_PERF_FIXED_CTRL_ENABLE 0x333

static int __init hello_init(void)
{
    int cpu;
    wrmsrl(MSR_CORE_PERF_FIXED_CTR_CTRL, IA32_PERF_FIXED_CTRL_ENABLE);
    wrmsrl(MSR_CORE_PERF_GLOBAL_CTRL, IA32_PERF_GLOBAL_CTRL_ENABLE);
    for_each_possible_cpu(cpu)
    {
        wrmsrl_on_cpu(cpu, MSR_P6_EVNTSEL0, LLC_EVENT);
    }
    return 0;
}

static void __exit hello_cleanup(void)
{
    int cpu;
    u64 val;
    for_each_possible_cpu(cpu)
    {
        rdmsrl_on_cpu(cpu, MSR_IA32_PERFCTR0, &val);
        printk(KERN_DEBUG "The LLC-Miss on core %i is: %llu\n", cpu, val);
    }
    printk(KERN_INFO "Cleaning up module.\n");
}

module_init(hello_init);
module_exit(hello_cleanup);
```